# how to get the list of azure logic apps present in a particular azure resource group using azure powershell commands

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-logic-apps

Say for Suppose i have Logic App 1 ,Logic App 2 ,Logic App 3 etc got created in an Azure Resource Group X. Then Using Azure Powershell Command, I want to get this list of logic apps present under 'X' Azure Resource Group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" -ResourceGroupName resourcegroupname
```

It works fine on my side.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell Core command should work; replace "myresourcegroup" with the name of the resource group you want to search. In Azure Cloud Shell you can access PowerShell Core by running `pwsh`.

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Logic/workflows" -ResourceGroupNameContains "myresourcegroup"
```

[image]

Comment: this will not give any result.